# value not displaying from json object in angular js

Tags: angularjs, json, jsp

I am trying to display the JSON object in JSP page using angular js.
The Data is coming correctly but display code is not working properly in JSP page.

**in app.js**

```
 $http.get(urlBase+'/users1').success(function (data){


for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

    alert(data[i]);



}

$scope.users=data;

 })
 .error(function(data) {
     alert("errore"+data);
     $scope.data = "error in fetching data";
 });
```

**jsp file**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"

    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html ng-app="taskManagerApp">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>AngularJS Task Manager</title>

<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>

<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/app.js"/>"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div ng-controller="taskManagerController">



   <span>Add Task</span>


  <div>

   <div>

    <table>

     <tr>

      <td> Name:</td>

      <td><input type="text" ng-model="Name"/></td>

     </tr>

     <tr>

      <td>City:</td>

      <td><input type="text" ng-model="City"/></td>

     </tr>


     <tr>

      <td>

<button ng-click="addTask()" class="btn-panel-big">Add New Task</button></td>

     </tr>

    </table>        

   </div>

  </div>


  <div>
  <table>
     <div ng-repeat="user in users">

     <tr>
     <td>hai  {{user.id}}</td>
     <td>hello  {{user.Name}}</td>
     <td>wellcome  {{user.city}}</td>

     </tr>

     </div>
  </table>

  </div>


  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

**ng-repeat** is also not working here. Is there any mistake while assigning the value to scope variable? Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: use the ng-repeat inside `tr` instead of `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ng-repeat="user in users"** should be added to the **tr** tag and not the **div** tag.